# I don't understand how this "os.join" function is working? I am getting errors constantly and no reading on os functions is helping me

Tags: python-2.7, relative-path, python-os

Here's the code

```
sys.path.append( "../tools/" )
from parse_out_email_text import parseOutText #(its just another .py file that has a function I wrote)

from_sara  = open("from_sara.txt", "r")
from_chris = open("from_chris.txt", "r")

from_data = []
word_data = []

temp_counter = 0

for name, from_person in [("sara", from_sara), ("chris", from_chris)]:
  for path in from_person:
    ### only look at first 200 emails when developing
    ### once everything is working, remove this line to run over full dataset
    temp_counter += 1
    if temp_counter < 200:
        path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1]) #(THIS IS THE PART I CAN'T GET MY HEAD AROUND)
        print path
        email = open(path, "r")

        email.close()

print "emails processed"
from_sara.close()
from_chris.close()
```

When I run this, it gives me an error as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
..\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101.
File "C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/Udacity/Naya_attempt/vectorize_text.py", line 47, in <module>
email = open(path, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101.'
```

I don't even have this """'..\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101.'""" directory path on my laptop, I tried to change the path by replacing the '..'  in the code by the actual path name to the folder where I keep all the files, and nothing changes.

```
path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1])
```

This code is part of an online course on machine learning and I have been stuck at this point for 3 hours now. Any help would be really appreciated.

(P.S. This is not a homework question and there are no grades attached to this, its a free online course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your test data is not there so it cannot find it. you should run start-up code again and make sure the necessary maildir are all there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools inside your udacity project directory and run startup.py.
It is about 400 Mb so sit back and relax!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is extremely late, but I found this post after having the exact same problem.

All the answers that I found here and on other sites, even the issue requests in the original github, were just "run startup.py" I already did that. However, it was telling me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "K:\documents\Udacity\Mini-Projects\ud120-projects\text_learning\vectorize_text.py", line 48, in <module>
    email = open(path, "r")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101.'
```

Just like yours. I then found where this file was located and it was indeed on my computer

I added 'tools' to the os.path.join() line as you can see here:

```
for name, from_person in [("sara", from_sara), ("chris", from_chris)]:
    for path in from_person:
        ### only look at first 200 emails when developing
        ### once everything is working, remove this line to run over full dataset
        temp_counter += 1
        if temp_counter < 200:
            #path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1])  <---original
            path = os.path.join('..','tools', path[:-1])
            print(path)
            email = open(path, "r")
```

This worked for me finally. So, I hope it helps anyone else that stumbles on this problem in the future.

Also, I noticed on some examples I found of other repos of the lessons. Their 'tools' folder was named 'utils'.

[Here is an example, this is a repo that someone tweaked to use jupyter notebooks to run the lessons](https://github.com/trsvchn/ud120-projects-py3-jupyter/blob/master/11-text-learning/vectorize_text.ipynb) So, use the one that you have.

Answer (score 0):

- In your Udacity course folder, first go to tools directory, check if you have `maildir` folder present and if it has got subfolders in it, if they are present then go back to `text_learning/vectorize_text.py`, find this line of code `path = os.path.join('..', path[:-1])`, change it to `path = os.path.join('../tools/', path[:-1])`,
- On terminal, `cd text_learning` , then `python vectorize_text.py`, this should solve the issue.
- If this does not solve the issue, then Go to tools inside your udacity project directory and run startup.py. Wait till the process is complete
- Repeat step 1.